# How can I speed up client server interaction for a mobile application receiving multiple images?

Tags: php, android, json, image-processing

I am new to mobile application development. I am working on a application where I create a Json file on a server for displaying a particular static page in my mobile application. This Json includes many images, so to reduce the number of hits on the server I convert these images into binary and then include them in the json file. This makes the json file very large which is causing the page loading on the mobile to be very slow.

Can someone tell me what should do so that file size remains within its limit and I can also reduce the number of requests to the server.

Also, is using a Restful API faster than http request anyhow?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on first run, save all your images.  next time dont hit the server. get the saved images and show them. that is the only way.

Comment: @Signare thanks for reply.. so should I continue working with binary form of images or I should change json pattern and send links of images?

Comment: Json contains url right, so you may use libraries for images

Comment: you can use binary of images.

Comment: I suggest you do not include the images in the JSON, but provide them as links and use a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the images in a background thread. This will make the basic page load quickly, and allow the images to be displayed as fast as the users net connection will allow.